# Difficulty with Vue transitions on rendered elements

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, vuejs2

**Vue 2.1.10**

I have a component that is responsible for sending email invites. The user enters the email address into an input box and clicks a button, which makes a request to the server. The server's response is assigned to the `inviteResponse` property of the component. A div element is then displayed:

```
<div v-if="inviteResponse != ''">{{ inviteResponse }}</div>
```

I want to make it so that, 3 seconds after it is displayed, this message slowly fades out. I've been trying to get this to work using [Vue Transition Effects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html), but haven't had luck so far. Here's what I've tried:

```
<transition name="element-fade" appear>
    <div v-if="inviteResponse != ''">{{ inviteResponse }}</div>
</transition>
```

CSS rules on the component:

```
<style scoped>
.element-fade-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}
.element-fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 3s ease;
    transition-delay: 3s;
}
.element-fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

According to the [official guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes), Vue should automatically detect these, start the leaving element at opacity 1, then after a 3 second delay transition it out over a 3 second period until it's gone.

In my case though, absolutely nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `inviteResponse = ''` somewhere in your code in order to hide your message. So that `v-if` statement becomes `false`.

For example, in your callback function after receiving server response you can 
`if (this.inviteResponse) {
    setTimeout(function() { this.inviteResponse = '' }, 3000);
}`

Comment: If i set `inviteResponse` to `''` then the text itself will disappear before the container div. I would need to create a brand new boolean property, like `displayInviteResponse` and fiddle with that. However, I was hoping to completely avoid `setTimeout`. Using that defeats the purpose of CSS transitions.